# Testing for Threat Safety in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, thread-safety, puma

Now that Puma is the recommended web server for Rails on Heroku, they are warning of the dangers of using non-threadsafe code.

How do you test a Rails app for thread safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally test thread safety by assigning and verifying the value of a variable. In a rspec:

- fork 2 processes
- first process would assign the variable with a value
- first process would pause for a second
- second process would assign the same variable with a different value

Expected: both variable have different values